# DbContext Generator - configuring for model in another namespace

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

With reference to [EF 4.1 DbContext Generattor - Put Entities in different project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349320/ef-4-1-dbcontext-generattor-put-entities-in-different-project) , what is required to get the DbContext to use the entities in another namespace? Do I need to edit the the DbContext template (and if so, how?) or do I need to edit the .edmx?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the EDMX-file reference in your T4-template file (.tt) and just save. It will show you a dialog.

Open the .tt-file and look for the following line:

```
   string inputFile = @"your-edmx-filename.edmx;
```

So change it so that it will point to the EDMX of the other project:

```
   string inputFile = @"..\Other-projects-folder\your-edmx-filename.edmx;
```

This approach is used in order to separate the DbContext / ObjectContext from the generated entities and make it i.e. part of your DAL which is a much better fit since it deals with your database.